# Restore a deleted CSS from loaded page on localhost in firefox

Tags: firefox, css

I was working on web project, and when i pushed my changes, my files disappeared because of bad manipulations. Now, I've lost my files, but my page is still Firefox memory, so I could copy the HTML code. But I cannot copy the CSS ! I've tried to recover deleted file using Quetek's utility, but the files are corrupted, and in the css I could see "heade", "master"... But not my CSS. Please help me !! I didn't closed Firefox. Vinz243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following:
In firefox you can try to name & save the page, and then select complete Site next to the saved file firefox will create a folder with the same name containing all the resources like images and CSS style-sheets.
You can also analyse the cache folder of firefox location may be different from on system to another.
You can also install the fire-bug plug-in and analyse the page.

And remember always backup your stuff.

Comment: Fortunately, in my commit browser i found the latest changes. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @falk - Did Firefox ever fix the bug where @imported style sheets didn't get saved under `Save All`?  There used to be a plugin to work around that issue.

Comment: @jeremy-j-starcher Oh I didn't know about this bug, and I also don't know if It's fixes, sry, I should reed more news.

Comment: @Falk - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126309